# How to get Java web application path?

Tags: java

I have a fileupload servlet in java. And i want to set path to upload folder, to it waork on any server. I say:

```
 File disk = new File("/myportlet/upload/"+item.getName());
 item.write(disk);
```

But nothing saved. When i use absolute path to upload folder all work fine.
So how to set path to upload folder in server?

Comment: You should be aware that you violate the servlet spec by wanting to write inside the server.

Comment: u can try with the getContextPath()

Comment: Look at the path. If the applet runs on linux, the first slash would set you to the root. Try `./myportlet/upload/`

Comment: This probably fails due to / being interpreted as "root of filesystem" in the File() constructor. As Thorbjørn writes above, you're violating the spec if you actually write to the server area. I'd suggest using a welldefined space on the filesystem for these files instead.

Comment: @looper you are not guaranteed that the current working directory is set to anything useful to you.

Comment: `getContextPath()` give me this path `/myportlet`. So i dont think that can help. And in work in Win not in Linux.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen that's right, didn't come to my mind.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen So if i translate your comment right its mean that i cant write files inside my application?

Comment: In addition to @Thomas's suggestion, you could configure the folder path in `web.xml` and load the absolute path of the file system from the configuration.

Comment: @Roy Ling but i dont know absolute path to application folder on server.

Comment: @KliverMax violating the spec does not imply you cannot, but that your application may break unexpectedly - e.g. in clustered servers (file written on A, processing happens on B) or in servers not exploding WAR files when deploying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading "/" at the `new File()` constructor refers to the root of the file system. The file will be written into a directory named `/myportlet/upload`, in your code.

As the comments implied, writing into appserver-internal directories violates the spec and is generally a terrible idea - I honestly can't think of one proper use for doing so. What you want to do is to read the target path from a parameter - for example, a servlet's initialization parameter or a context initialization parameter - and use that.

Comment: `servlet's initialization parameter or a context initialization parameter - and use that.` Can you give a example? Im not good in java.

Comment: Google is your best friend here... :-) see this for example: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html#initParams

Answer (score 2):

I used the below snippet. It worked fine in windows server.

```
File f=new File("sample.xls");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos=null;
        if(f != null){
            fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(b);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
```